# My images for an html work locally but not all show up when deployed through heroku

Tags: html, image, heroku

the images are saved .jpg.

A background image works, even though it isnt the image i want.
Also two more images further down the site do not show either.
Everything works fine locally.

```
thanks. 
<div id="container">
<div id="services" class="row">
  <div id="Srvc" class="col-md-6">
    <img class="imgCircle" src="assests/images/front-sun.jpg" alt="Finished Lawn">
    <h3>Landscape Design and Maintenance</h3>
    <p>generic para..Never worry about your front or backyard looking as beautiful as the first day it was installed when  is in charge of your yard care and maintenance. Get a free yard care estimate today</p>
  </div>
  <div id="Srvc" class="col-md-6">
     <img class="imgCircle" src="assests/images/wall.jpg" alt="Retaining Wall">
    <h3>Masonry Solutions</h3>
    <p> generic para...Never worry about your front or backyard looking as beautiful as the first day it was installed when is in charge of your yard care and maintenance. Get a free yard care estimate today</p>
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: Please post the source as text, not as an image

Comment: ok thanks, how about now?